# Spring bean of type Map<String, Object> is special?

Tags: java, spring

Platform: JDK 11, Spring Boot 2.6.6 / Spring 5.3.18

For reasons related to a dependency, I found myself wanting to create and then inject a bean of type `Map<String, Object>`.  There seems to be something special about this type, though, as I will demonstrate.

Minimal illuminating code sample:

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ThingyTest {
  @Bean("someOtherBean")
  Object otherBean(@Qualifier("mapBean") Map<String, Object> map) {
    return map.keySet();
  }
  
  @Bean("mapBean")
  Map<String, Object> mapBean() {
    return Map.of(
        "key1", "value1",
        "key2", "value2");
  }
}
```

My desire is for the parameter named `map` to contain:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2", "value2"
}
```

However, it actually contains:

```
{
    "mapBean": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2
    }
}
```

If I change the type of `mapBean` (in both the method return type and the method argument) to `Map<String, String>` then I get the desired behavior, but I have to do some nasty type wrangling to get back to the `Map<String, Object>` that I need.

I've spent many hours searching the Internet and Spring documentation for any discussion of this apparent "feature."  I'm sure this behavior is intentional, but I just can't find any documentation or explanation of it.
Ideally, someone could explain how to get my desired behavior, but I would be satisfied with references to official documentation describing the observed behavior.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that happens is that the Spring container kicks in and uses it to inject all the beans from the context (as described [here in the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation) (scroll down to the map section)). Instead of injecting the bean you could try `return mapBean().keySet()`. However why return an `Object` if you actually want a `Set<String>`?

Comment: @M.Deinum yeah I saw that in the docs, but it didn't go into enough detail to explain this particular behavior.
I'm really not sure where you got that I want a `Set<String>`.  That's not the case.

Comment: That is what your `otherBean` method is returning (although the method signature is an `Object`).

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad --- that's a red herring (insufficiently carefully constructed example code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Map<String, ?>` is a bit of a special case in the Spring Framework.

> Even typed `Map` instances can be autowired as long as the expected key type is `String`. The map values contain all beans of the expected type, and the keys contain the corresponding bean names, as the following example shows:

As your `Map` has a type `Object` it will inject a `Map` with all the beans in the application context.

To workaround this you could try the following

```java
@Configuration
public class ThingyTest {
  @Bean("someOtherBean")
  Object otherBean() {
    return mapBean().keySet();
  }
  
  @Bean("mapBean")
  Map<String, Object> mapBean() {
    return Map.of(
        "key1", "value1",
        "key2", "value2");
  }
}
```

Although this might be a workaround I would consider registering a bug with the Spring Framework. As you have added an `@Qualifier` it is to be expected that that specific bean would be taken and not the special case of `Map<String, ?>`.

Comment: Yeah so this makes sense, except for the part that the injected Map only contains the one bean (the full context has dozens, and that's true even in an otherwise brand new Spring project) and moreover that one bean is the one specified by the `@Qualifier`.

Comment: Hence the suggestion to raise the bug, as the behavior seems/feels weird. You should either get the bean mentioned, or all the beans from the context, but you now get some in between hybrid thing that isn't documented. I can also not imagine that that is how it is supposed to work. Se please go to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues and create an issue so it can be fixed.